# Application name from InstallValidate dialogue is different with one from ARP

Tags: dialog, wix

I currently met an issue with application name in InstallValidate dialogue (this can be brought up from leaving the application open whilst installing a newer version) is somehow different with the one in Add/Remove Program entry. I've been looking up on google with no luck.

The desired application name display correctly in all other places apart from that InstallValidate dialogue..any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about the "files in use" dialog, MSI uses the title of the process's top-level window.

Comment: it turns out the reason that listed item in 'file in use' dialog has different name than the one from APR is because it reads from 'file description' of the file.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out the reason that listed item in 'file in use' dialog has different name than the one from APR is because it reads from 'file description' of the file.